# Facial Recognition using election framework

Tags: html, node.js, npm, electron

Is it possible to code for facial recognition program in electron framework. I understand code will be in .html and .js, I looked for all the tutorials and have been doing my research on this topic but very little is present based on electron. 
I'll be very thankful if anyone can point me in right direction or help me with code it's all for my project which I need to submit within 2 weeks.

Comment: You cannot do facial recognition in HTML and Javascript, or at least: you shouldn't. You probably need to use a service API that does it for you, and then you can output the result in HTML and Javascript. Old link, but useful: http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/50-face-recognition-apis

Comment: As I read, in electron APIs will be used with html and js to build up programs. First thing - is it possible to build a facial recognition program in electron? Second - is there any possibility of finding such code from which I can get help to finish my work? Thanks a lot ✌

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in Electron applications you can use all Node modules.

In this example you can use one of the following modules from npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/face-detect
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/faced
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/face-analytics

Or you can use an external service like Watson Visual Recognition, see:

- https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition.html

To easily use the Watson API in Electron app you can use the `watson-developer-cloud` module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud

For more info see:

- https://developer.ibm.com/watson/
- https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/
- https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/